# Passing data to helper (including tags)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a helper function, which is called inside a haml template. It uses `xpath` to modify the content of `data`. To ensure this working, `data` must be valid `html`. The following example fails, because `data` is not valid html.

```
%pre
  = foo(data)
```

The idea now, is to wrap `data` into the `pre` tag, and pass this valid `html` to `foo` like the following.

```
= foo("<pre>#{data}</pre>")
```

Is something like that possible in haml? Without using string manipulation?
The solution should work for any kind of tags. For example it should work for headings:

```
%h1.title
  = foo(heading_data)
```

Comment: Do you have any specifics on the error?

Comment: `xpath` simply won't work, if it's not valid html.

Answer (score 0):

**Data**

Firstly what are you sending pure HTML to a helper?

As is the case in most programming, the "arguments" you send to a helper are just ways to call a method. This means you just send the most succinct data you need, and let the helper / method output it as you require.

Frankly, I'd recommend **against** sending the data file you're looking at.

---

**Recommendation**

Without knowing what your `foo` method is all about, I'd recommend this:

```
#view
= foo data

#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
class ApplicationHelper
   def foo data
      code = "<pre>#{data}</pre>"
      return raw code
   end
end
```

Comment: `foo` is modifying given data using `xpath`. For this, I needed to ensure that the data is valid `html` --> therefore wrap it first into tags. The example is nice, but I'm looking for a more general way, such that it works for different kind of tags, not just the pre tag.

Comment: Okay I suppose your update gives it more context, which I actually agree with. Can you update your question with the specifics you just outlined?

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear to me what you are trying to do, but it sounds to me that the usage of your function should instead be along the lines of

```
= foo do
  %pre= data
```

or

```
= foo do
  %h1= data
```

in the second case. To support this, your foo function should look like

```
def foo(&block)
  data = capture(&block)
  # transform data and return it
  # Don't forget about html safety!
end
```

Here `data` will be set to the result of evaluating the block of markup that was passed to your `foo` method